# No Method Error, Call methods from different classes, Passing Arguments

Tags: ruby

Can someone please help a newb?  I am getting the error of;

```
: undefined method `computer_name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I thought in ruby you call the method with a .method_name?
Is it because my initialize method is not correct?  Not correctly passing arguments?

```
load 'admin_logic.rb'
load 'computer_logic.rb'
load 'user_logic.rb'

class TicTacToe
  def initialize(admin_object, computer_object, user_object)
    admin_object = Admin.new
    computer_object = ComputerLogic.new
    user_object = UserLogic.new
    @new_game = TicTacToe.new(admin_object, computer_object, user_object)
  end
end

puts "Hello, I\'m " + @new_game.computer_name + ", let\'s play Tic Tac Toe!  What is your name?"

puts "Great " + @new_game.user_name + ", you\'ll be " + @new_game.user_sign + ".  Please choose where you want to go."

puts 'The game board is the following, please remember!'
puts ' a1 | a2 | a3'
puts " --- --- ---"
puts ' b1 | b2 | b3'
puts " --- --- ---"
puts ' c1 | c2 | c3'

@new_game.user_sign
@new_game.computer_sign
@new_game.game_board
@new_game.winning_propositions

while @new_game .computer_win != true do
  @new_game.user_turn
  @new_game.draw_game_outcome
  @new_game.player_first_turn_check?
  @new_game.draw_game_outcome
end
```

MY CLASS THAT I AM CALLING IT FROM - ADMIN.RB

```
class Admin
  def computer_name
    @computer_name = "Watson"
  end
end
```

Comment: I dno't see a `require 'admin'` line.

Comment: Or rather `require 'ADMIN'` since it is in call caps.

Comment: But, after that is done, you need to have call that method on an instance of the class for which it exists.

Answer (score 2):

You are currently setting `@new_game` **INSIDE** of your class. You are attempting to use it **OUTSIDE** of your class. The variable scope will not allow you to do this.

What you want to do is something like the following.

```
class TicTacToe
  def initialize(admin_object, computer_object, user_object)
    admin_object = Admin.new
    computer_object = ComputerLogic.new
    user_object = UserLogic.new
  end
end

@new_game = TicTacToe.new(admin_object, computer_object, user_object)
```

That will create an instance of your `TicTacToe` class that you can then use your defined methods on.

Comment: I did try this and got an error; : undefined local variable or method `admin_object' for main:Object (NameError)
~/coding/TicTacToe:

Comment: I think you need to read up on Object Oriented Programming, variable scope in Ruby, and possibly google your errors.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how objects work. Your initializer is calling itself to start with.

This may be a better starting point, but please take some time to do some basic reading about OOP:

```
class Admin
  def name
    "Watson"
  end
  alias_method :to_s, :name
end

class TicTacToe
  attr_reader :admin_object, :computer_object, :user_object

  def initialize
    @admin_object = Admin.new
    @computer_object = ComputerLogic.new
    @user_object = UserLogic.new
  end
end

@new_game = TicTacToe.new
```

Check out some tutorials, eg. https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/2/

Comment: do you know why I would get this error when trying this? : undefined local variable or method `admin_object' for main:Object (NameError) ~/coding/TicTacToe: –

Comment: Yeah, I updated the answer a bit as you actually don't need to pass any *_objects to the initializer.